# Memory leak when updating material index in function animate() - three.js r84

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, three.js

Inspired by ParametricGeometries ( @author zz85 ),  I have programmed an addon for three.js (named THREEf, updated 22.03.) to produce with only 9 properties, 18 functions and 1 array almost infinite many time-varying geometries:

```
geometry =  new THREE.Geometry();
geometry.createMorphGeometry = THREEf.createMorphGeometry; // insert the methode from THREEf.js
geometry.createMorphGeometry(); // apply the methode ( here without parameters: all default )
```

After a while I noticed a memory leak. I thought I had made a mistake and searched the entire code. But nothing found! The error then suddenly disappeared when some code blocks were removed. The error occurs when the material index is renewed in the animate function.

```
geometry.faces[ index ].materialIndex  = geometry.materialCover( .. , .. , t ); // in THREEf
```

respectively ( in animate() )

```
t = clock.getElapsedTime(); 
geometry.elementsNeedUpdate = true;  // sufficient
// geometry.colorsNeedUpdate = true;
// material.needsUpdate = true;
geometry.faces[ 0 ].materialIndex = Math.floor( 5 * t ) % 3;
```

in the following very simple example that results in a fairly slow memory allocation.

```js
'use strict'
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 2000 );
camera.position.set( 10, 20, 30 );

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
renderer.setClearColor( 0xdddddd, 1 ); 

var container = document.createElement( 'div' );
document.body.appendChild( container );
container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

var orbit = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
orbit.enableZoom = true;

var clock  = new THREE.Clock( true ); 
var t; // time

var materials = [

  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0000, side: THREE.DoubleSide } ), // red
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00, side: THREE.DoubleSide } ), // green
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x0000ff, side: THREE.DoubleSide } )  // blue  
  
 ];
 
var material = new THREE.MultiMaterial( materials ); 

var geometry =  new THREE.Geometry();

geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( -10, -10, -10 ) );
geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3(  10, -10,   0 ) );
geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3(  10,  10,  10 ) );

var face = new THREE.Face3( 0, 1, 2 );

geometry.faces.push( face );
scene.add( new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material ) );

animate();
//...............

function animate() {

 requestAnimationFrame( animate );
 
 t = clock.getElapsedTime();  
 
 geometry.elementsNeedUpdate = true; 
 //geometry.colorsNeedUpdate = true;
 //material.needsUpdate = true;
 
 geometry.faces[ 0 ].materialIndex = Math.floor( 5 * t ) % 3;
 
 renderer.render( scene, camera );
 controls.update();
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- memory leak -->
<html lang="de"><head><title> memory leak </title>  <meta charset="utf-8" /></head>
<body>   memory leak when updating material index in function animate()</body>
<script src="../js/three.min.84.js"></script>
<script src="../js/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

See under http://threejs.hofk.de/memoryleak/memoryLeak.html

In my "function geometry", the browser crashes faster. You can try this at http://sandbox.threejs.hofk.de/ (currently only with Firefox) 
and there is a way to basic examples - also other browsers.
There is a library of forms in progress.

I have looked in three.js but this is really great and I have too little knowledge to recognize something there.

How to fix the memory leak?

Comment: Note, the memory leak in THREEf is fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After WestLangley had answered my Question ( to change the face colors ) I have looked for many examples.
I have found the following: 
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_objects_update.html

**And in this example the answer is.**

To change the faces you need

```
geometry.elementsNeedUpdate = true;
```

but to change the material index is used

```
geometry.groupsNeedUpdate = true;
```

---

This update is not available in the documentation
"How to update things" where I've looked.
There is the enumeration

```
object.updateMatrix();
```

...

```
geometry.elementsNeedUpdate = true;
```

...

```
texture.needsUpdate = true;
```

Then I looked in three.js revision 84 to the function DirectGeometry ().
I found  this.groupsNeedUpdate = ...
It can be seen that the material index is related to the group.

*Conclusion:*

I just had to change a single command instead
geometry.elementsNeedUpdate = true;
 now
geometry.groupsNeedUpdate = true;
and the sandbox has no memory leak anymore.

---

But if I want to change the faces as in the example https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_objects_update.html
there is still a problem.

I used the test 50 (given 1000 slowly)

`function animate() { setTimeout( animate, 50 ); ...`

Then the memory leak occurs:

```
function randomizeFaces( object ) { ... geometry.elementsNeedUpdate = true; ...
```

I think then you have to use shader.